# Checking Windows Update on Server 2012 R2

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2

I have a server Windows 2012 R2, when i am checking for windows updates it gives me this error:

Windows.immersive control panel.

Is there any solution on this matter?

Answer (score 1):

Try to run the Command Prompt (cmd) as administrator and enter :

```
cd \Windows
ren ImmersiveControlPanel ImmersiveControlPanel.old
sfc /scannow
```

Sfc may take some time, but it should rebuild `ImmersiveControlPanel`.

Reboot and try again, and if all is well, you may delete `ImmersiveControlPanel.old`.

For more information, see
[How to Run SFC Command to Repair System Files in Windows 10](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like some of your system files are broken. You can try to:

run **cmd.exe** as Administrator, then type **sfc /scannow** and wait for the process to complete.

Hope this helps.